# zsh: command not found: jhipster Catalina mac

Tags: jhipster, zsh, macos-catalina

I just upgrade my Mac to Catalina.

When I do `jhipster import-jdl Model.jdl`

It gives

```
zsh: command not found: jhipster Catalina Mac
```

What do I have to do?

I don't have a `~/.zshrc` file.

Do I have to create it and add the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just reinstalled jhispter

```
sudo npm install -g generator-jhipster
```

and is working!